# Nginx after installling is down?

Tags: apache, nginx

I've tried to install nginx on my vps buy following this steps

```
cd /usr/local/src

wget http://nginxcp.com/latest/nginxadmin.tar 

tar xf nginxadmin.tar

cd publicnginx

./nginxinstaller install
```

finnaly the apache in tweak seting checked working on port 8081 but the server still gives errors and nginx status is `down`.

this is the error when i restart apache from ssh

```
Restarting nginx daemon: nginxnginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family 

not supported by protocol)
 already running.
```

Comment: This question is probably better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: thank u ill post it there